# Libreoffice Calc Sum of values depending of month and year of a range of dates

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'm quite new to Libreoffice and Spreadscheetprograms generally, please keep it in mind.

I have a very large spreadsheet with following data

- Column C - Date in form of DD.MM.YYYY range form 2013 to 2017
- Column E - Numbers (Positive and negative values)

I need to get added all values in column E with following criteria

- for a month (for example 05 - May)
- of a year (for example 2015)
- which are either positive or negative (I will have two formulas, one
  for the sum of all positive numbers and another for the negatives)

I hope I explained it correctly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please try for one:

```
=SUMIFS(E:E,C:C,">"&DATEVALUE("30/4/2015"),C:C,"<"&DATEVALUE("1/6/2015"),E:E,">0")
```

and reverse the final angle bracket for the other (for the example of May 2015).